# SUMPRODUCT function to count only visible rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, sumproduct

I'm trying to do a countif using the sumproduct function to only count visible rows. However, it gives me the exact number as if there is no filter at all. Could you please help check my formula? Thanks!

| Date | Name | Available? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Person 1 | Yes |
| Monday | Person 2 | Yes |
| Tuesday | Person 1 | No |
| Tuesday | Person 2 | Yes |
| ......... |  |  |

All Date, Name and Available? has data filter on them. When I filter the table to look at Tuesday only, I'd like to count how many Yes'es are on Tuesday.

I should give me the result = 1. However, my formula gives result = 3, which is wrong :(

What I wrote

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J7:J1000= "Yes")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(J7,ROW(J7:J1000)-MIN(ROW(J7:J1000)),0))))
```

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'm using Google Sheet, not Excel. And here is the image: https://imgur.com/HzdaR2Y. There are some hundreds of row. The green cell is colour-formatted for "Yes". J4 should be 3 (3 green cells), but right now it says 42 which is a simple sumif of all "Yes" without the filter

Comment: I assume they use the same functions? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this formula. It uses SUBTOTAL with option 103 (COUNTA) to filter out the rows that are hidden. And put that filtered range inside COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(J2:J,BYROW(J2:J,LAMBDA(e,SUBTOTAL(103,e)))),"yes")
```

Try it and let me know!

Comment: Haha, well, I'm glad it was useful! I haven't thought solution of this before, so it's not an useful tool for the future for myself too! Good luck!